# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown menus not functioning - But works on other file with same CDNs

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, cdn

I was trying to make the navbar-brand logo a dropdown toggle for my navbar. When I first implemented it, it worked fine! However, after editing my home page file and logged into access the main.php page, it suddenly stopped working.

I dont usually show all of my code but for this case, I will so please forgive me for that.

I tried copying and pasting a generic navbar into the echo"" portion, and the dropdown did not work. That gave me the idea that it had something to do with the cdns I was using. So I copied and pasted to another file and it worked. Which confused me. When I went back to the main.php file I thought it could have been a bad cache. I emptied it and it still did not work. Understand that this was working 100% fine until I edited my home page and logged back in.

Also, I ruled out my css file because I commented it out and tried it without that. So here is a list of things it was not:

1.Bad Cache
2.CSS file
3.CDN's not matching with the bootstrap4 version I am using.
4.Haunted computer

```
<?php
   require "login.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Main</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm' crossorigin='anonymous'>
    <link rel ='stylesheet' href='register.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo"<h1 align = 'Center'>You have not logged in.</h1>";
      }
      else{
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        echo"
        <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light'>
        <div class='navbar-brand dropdown'>
          <a class = 'dropdown-toggle' id='navbarDropdown' role='button' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
            $username
          </a>
          <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdown'>
              <a class='dropdown-item' href='endSession.php'>Logout</a>
              <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Account</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
          <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>

        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
          <ul class='navbar-nav mr-auto'>
            <li class='nav-item active'>
              <a class='nav-link' href='#'>Coming Soon <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class='mx-2 my-auto mx-auto search-bar d-inline w-50'>
            <div class = 'input-group'>
                <input class=' form-control mr-sm-2' type='text' placeholder='Search Contacts' aria-label='Search'>
                <span class='input-group-append'>
                <button class='btn btn-outline-success' type='submit'>GO</button>
                </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>";
      }
    ?>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT_CDN -->
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
  </body>
```

I expect my dropdowns to work.

Also another interesting bit,  the hamburger menu works sort of... it does not de-toggle though.

This issue is confusing.

Comment: Try using <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> minified version and avoid slim that causes problem most of the time

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure what happen but try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pos-f-t">
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
      <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <ul class='navbar-nav mr-auto'>
          <li class='nav-item active'>
            <a class='nav-link' href='#'>Coming Soon <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class='mx-2 my-auto mx-auto search-bar d-inline w-50'>
          <div class='input-group'>
            <input class=' form-control mr-sm-2' type='text' placeholder='Search Contacts' aria-label='Search'>
            <span class='input-group-append'>
                <button class='btn btn-outline-success' type='submit'>GO</button>
                </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="navbar-brand dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    $username
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class='dropdown-item' href='endSession.php'>Logout</a>
          <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Account</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the CDN's at the bottom. That seemed to have worked. 
Turns out login.php was being imported with the CDNs in PHP. At least that is my theory.